# How to normalise CSV content in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, csv

## Problem:

**I'm looking for a PHP function to easily and efficiently normalise CSV content in a string (not in a file).** I have made a function for that. I provide it in an answer, because it is a possible solution. Unfortuanately it doesn't work when the separator is included in incomming string values.

**Can anyone provide a better solution?**

## Why not using fputcsv / fgetcsv ?

Because:

- it requires at least PHP 5.1.0 (which is sometimes not available)
- it can only read from files, but not from a string. even though, sometimes the input is not a file (eg. if you fetch the CSV from an email)
- putting the content into a temporary file might be unavailable due to security policies.

## Why / what kind of normalisation?

Normalise in a way, that the encloser encloses every field. Because the encloser can be optional and different per line and per field. This can happen if one is implementing unclean/incomplete specifications and/or using CSV content from different sources/programs/developers.

### Example function call:

```
$csvContent = "'a a',\"b\",c,1, 2 ,3 \n a a,'bb',cc, 1, 2, 3 ";
echo "BEFORE:\n$csvContent\n";
normaliseCSV($csvContent);
echo "AFTER:\n$csvContent\n";
```

### Output:

```
BEFORE:
'a a',"b",c,1, 2 ,3 
a a,'bb',cc, 1, 2, 3 
AFTER:
"a a","b","c","1","2","3"
"a a","bb","cc","1","2","3"
```

Comment: Isn't [tmpfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) available by default, unless you specifically disable it with security restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

To specifically address your concern regarding `f*csv` working only with files:

1. Since PHP 5.3 there's [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv).
2. For at least PHP >= 5.1 (and I really hope that's the oldest you'll have to deal with these days), you can use stream wrappers:

   ```
   $buffer = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
   fwrite($buffer, $string);
   rewind($buffer);

   fgetcsv($buffer) ..
   ```

   Or obviously the reverse if you want to use `fputcsv`.

Comment: deceze nice answer , but for those PHP <5.1  i think my answer below would be nice approach ;-) expect your comments

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution. But it doesn't consider the case that the separator (,) might be included in incoming strings.

```
function normaliseCSV(&$csv,$lineseperator = "\n", $fieldseperator = ',', $encloser = '"')
{
    $csvArray = explode ($lineseperator,$csv);
    foreach ($csvArray as &$line)
    {
        $lineArray = explode ($fieldseperator,$line);
        foreach ($lineArray as &$field)
        {
            $field = $encloser.trim($field,"\0\t\n\x0B\r \"'").$encloser;
        }
        $line = implode ($fieldseperator,$lineArray);
    }
    $csv = implode ($lineseperator,$csvArray);
}
```

It is a simple chain of `explode` -> `explode` -> `trim` -> `implode` -> `implode` .

Comment: so you are saying that the fiel separator could be as part of the field content without being encapsulated in enclosers ? ....

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus No. That would make the CSV wrong and non deterministic. This function doesn't handle incoming commas, even if they are properly enclosed.

Comment: that´s what i thought... your problem is in the second explode ... let me see what i have got in my arsenal ... one other question is limited the type of enclosers ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @deceze that you could expect atleast 5.1 these days, i'm sure there are some internal company servers somewhere who don't want to update.

I altered your method to be able to use field and line separators between double quotes, or in your case the `$encloser` value.

```
<?php

/*
In regards to the specs on http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 I use the following rules:

- "Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes." 
- "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote." 

Exception:
Even though the specs says use double quotes, I 'm using your $encloser variable

*/

echo normaliseCSV('a,b,\'c\',"d,e","f","g""h""i","""j"""' . "\n" . "\"k\nl\nm\"");


function normaliseCSV($csv,$lineseperator = "\n", $fieldseperator = ',', $encloser = '"')
{
    //We need 4 temporary replacement values
    //line seperator, fieldseperator, double qoutes, triple qoutes
    $keys = array();
    while (count($keys)<3) {
        $tmp = "##".md5(rand().rand().microtime())."##";
        if (strpos($csv, $tmp)===false) {
            $keys[] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    //first we exchange "" (double $encloser) and """ to make sure its not exploded
    $csv = str_replace($encloser.$encloser.$encloser, $keys[0], $csv);
    $csv = str_replace($encloser.$encloser, $keys[0], $csv);

    //Explode on $encloser
    //Every odd index is within quotes
    //Exchange line and field seperators for something not used.
    $content = explode($encloser,$csv);
    $len = count($content);
    if ($len>1) {
        for ($x=1;$x<$len;$x=$x+2) {
            $content[$x] = str_replace($lineseperator,$keys[1], $content[$x]);
            $content[$x] = str_replace($fieldseperator,$keys[2], $content[$x]);
        }
    }
    $csv = implode('',$content);


    $csvArray = explode ($lineseperator,$csv);
    foreach ($csvArray as &$line)
    {
            $lineArray = explode ($fieldseperator,$line);
            foreach ($lineArray as &$field)
            {
                    $val = trim($field,"\0\t\n\x0B\r '");
                    //put back the exchanged values
                    $val = str_replace($keys[0],$encloser.$encloser,$val);
                    $val = str_replace($keys[1],$lineseperator,$val);
                    $val = str_replace($keys[2],$fieldseperator,$val);

                    $val = $encloser.$val.$encloser;


                    $field = $val;

            }
            $line = implode ($fieldseperator,$lineArray);
    }
    $csv = implode ($lineseperator,$csvArray);


    return $csv;

}
?>
```

Output would be:

```
"a","b","c","d,e","f","g""h""i","""j"""
"k
l
m"
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/aGm6Tk2L)

Comment: just tested this. This solution doesn't work for quoted empty values. converts "" to """". While normal empty values that are coming in like ,, are correctly ransformed to ,"", .... Empty strings are valid CSV afaik.

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut  and Hugo Delsing please check my answer below, i think i got it ...

Answer (score 0):

when i first read this question wasn´t sure if it should be solved or not, since <5.1 environments should be extinguished a long time ago, dispite of that is a hell of a question how to solve this so we should be thinking wich approach to take... and my guess is it should be char by char examination.

I have separated logic in three main scenarios:

```
A: CHAR is a separator
B: CHAR is a Fuc$€/& quotation
C: CHAR is a Value
```

Obtaining as a reulst this weapon class (including log for it) for our arsenal:

```
<?php

    Class CSVParser 
    {
        #basic requirements
        public $input;
        public $separator;

        public $currentQuote;
        public $insideQuote;
        public $result;
        public $field;

        public $quotation = array();
        public $parsedArray = array();

        # for logging purposes only 
        public $logging = TRUE;
        public $log = array();

        function __construct($input, $separator, $quotation=array())
        {
            $this->separator = $separator;
            $this->input     = $input;
            $this->quotation = $quotation;
        }
        /**
        * The main idea is to go through the string to parse char by char to analize
        * when a complete field is detected it´ll be quoted according and added to an array 
        */
        public function parse()
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($this->input); $i++){
                $this->processStream($i);               
                }
            foreach($this->parsedArray as $value)
            {
                if(!is_null($value))
                    $this->result .= '"'.addslashes($value).'",';
            }
            return rtrim($this->result, ',');
        }


        private function processStream($i)
        {
            #A case (its a separator)
            if($this->input[$i]===$this->separator){
                $this->log("A", $this->input[$i]);
                if($this->insideQuote){
                    $this->field .= $this->input[$i];
                }else
                {
                    $this->saveField($this->field);
                    $this->field = NULL;
                }
            }

            #B case (its a f"·%$% quote)
            if(in_array($this->input[$i], $this->quotation)){
                $this->log("B", $this->input[$i]);
                if(!$this->insideQuote){
                    $this->insideQuote  = TRUE;
                    $this->currentQuote = $this->input[$i];
                }
                else{
                    if($this->currentQuote===$this->input[$i]){
                        $this->insideQuote = FALSE;
                        $this->currentQuote ='';
                        $this->saveField($this->field);
                        $this->field = NULL;        
                    }else{
                        $this->field .= $this->input[$i];
                    }

                }
            }

            #C case (its a value :-) )
            if(!in_array($this->input[$i], array_merge(array($this->separator), $this->quotation))){
                $this->log("C", $this->input[$i]);
                $this->field .= $this->input[$i];
            }


        }

        private function saveField($field)
        {
            $this->parsedArray[] = $field;
        }

        private function log($type, $value)
        {
            if($this->logging){
                $this->log[] = "CASE ".$type." WITH ".$value." AS VALUE";
            }
        }
    }
```

and example of how to use it would be:

```
$original = 'a,"ab",\'ab\'';
$test = new CSVParser($original, ',', array('"', "'"));

    echo "<PRE>ORIGINAL: ".$original."</PRE>";
    echo "<PRE>PARSED: ".$test->parse()."</PRE>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($test->log);
    echo "</pre>";
```

and here are the results:

```
ORIGINAL: a,"ab",'ab'
PARSED: "a","ab","ab"
Array
(
    [0] => CASE C WITH a AS VALUE
    [1] => CASE A WITH , AS VALUE
    [2] => CASE B WITH " AS VALUE
    [3] => CASE C WITH a AS VALUE
    [4] => CASE C WITH b AS VALUE
    [5] => CASE B WITH " AS VALUE
    [6] => CASE A WITH , AS VALUE
    [7] => CASE B WITH ' AS VALUE
    [8] => CASE C WITH a AS VALUE
    [9] => CASE C WITH b AS VALUE
    [10] => CASE B WITH ' AS VALUE
)
```

I might have mistakes since i only dedicated 25 mins to it, so any comment will be appreciated an edited.

Comment: i gues this is only cause i put in the quotations array the options " and ' , no double quotes...